# New Image not Rendering in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have just added a new loading wheel to my site in assets/images/loading.gif. The gif does work in development, but in production, the browser renders a broken image icon, with no errors. The server is showing the file as 0 bytes, but when I locate the file in the terminal, I can see that it is 3.2k. Other images from assets/images do work. After searching, I tried several things including precompile and changing lines in my config, but as yet, none have worked. Could it be a permissions or a caching issue?

**Solved:**

The issue was a referencing issue. I was initially referencing the gif in straight html, like so...

```
<img src="assets/loading.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
```

but when I used image_tag and changed the file path, it now works.

```
<%= image_tag("loading.gif", :id => "loading-indicator", :style => "display:none") %>
```

Not sure why it worked on my local initially.

Comment: how are you referencing the image in code?

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happened to me after I upgraded to Cedar on Heroku, so I'm guessing you're using Heroku to host your Rails 3.1 app on Cedar.

If so try this in your config/environments/production.rb file comment out the following line:

```
config/environments/production.rb
===================================
...
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
...
```

And replace it with this new line:

```
config/environments/production.rb
===================================
...
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil # For Heroku
...
```