# Rails: image exists but is not rendered in production even though rendered in development

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3, browser

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344960/image-url-path-on-server-not-rendered-in-normal-window-but-in-incognito-it-is), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909030/new-image-not-rendering-in-rails-3-1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597613/ruby-on-rails-image-tag-cannot-find-local-image), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773761/rails-4-and-leaflet-assets-images-not-found), but they don't address the problem.

We have a locally stored image that is rendered in the development environment.

In production, however, the image doesn't render. Accessing the image URL from the browser gets redirected to the 404 page because the image isn't found for some reason. Other images in the same directory are rendered without issue.

Details :-

- Image 1 URL: https://test.com/designs/thumbnails/foo/bar1.jpg
- Image 2 URL: https://test.com/designs/thumbnails/foo/bar2.jpg
- Entering both image URLs directly into the browser yields different results. Image 1 will render, but image 2 won't. Image 2 redirects to the 404 page.
- This isn't a caching issue, rendering in incognito fails.
- Both images exist in the directory.
- This seems to occur for new images, though the pattern isn't clear (i.e., some new images render but not all do).
- Image rendering code: `<img class="thumbnail" src="<%= design["thumbnailURL"] %>">` where `design["thumbnailURL"]` is an relative URL to the image (which, yes, does exist).
- We use `Rails 3.2` and Cloudflare.
- Server stack:

  - Passenger AppPreloader Version: 6.0.2
  - Instance: ElIQgS48 (nginx/1.15.8 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.2)
  - Ruby version: ruby 2.1.2p95
  - Operating system: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
  - PHP 7.0.33
  - Server version: 5.5.60-MariaDB MariaDB Server
  - Postfix mail_version = 2.10.1
  - Dovecot version: 2.2.36 (1f10bfa63)

Comment: Can you share what your routes look like?

Comment: are you using any cdn?

Comment: can you show the lines using the images? like image_tag

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari yes, using cloudflare. purging the cache doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @kevinluo201 just updated the question.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy sorry for the late reply. The routes file is pretty long; is there something you think could be wrong that causes this behavior?

Comment: You have option to bypass  Cloudflare, please try that ( maybe enabling Dev mode )

Comment: @Crashalot have you tried from different browsers ?

Comment: Can you please check your `Rails.application.assets.paths` on production.

Comment: @shrikant1712 thanks for the suggestion. to be clear, what should we check for as we're not actively using `Rails.application.assets.paths`?

Comment: if o/p of `Rails.application.assets.paths` returns empty then might you have an issue while loading assets. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths

Comment: I'm not sure about CLoudfare, but on Heroku you have to enable static assets. Is there anything like that on Cloudfare?

Answer (score 1):

If you host your files in public folder and don't use assets pipeline, it is often the job of the HTTP webserver (apache, nginx ...) to serve static files directly. They do that well and fast.

Please give more details about your production hosting setup (webserver, config etc), as well as the urls generated by Rails for your pictures. I'll update the answer accordingly, with relevant webserver config so that your static files get served directly.

Comment: getting details on webserver. urls generated by rails are of the form  https://test.com/designs/thumbnails/foo/bar1.jpg.

Comment: updated q with stack details. thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide NGINX configuration

Comment: are there specific details about the nginx configuration you want or just the whole file from '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at you example https://www.test.com/designs/thumbnails/foo/bar1.jpg and then I inspected yout image tag and I saw `<img src="img/test.com-logo.png" alt="Test.com create tests">` I was able to update it to `<img src="/img/test.com-logo.png" alt="Test.com create tests">` and I was able to see your logo.

you can update your erb from `<img class="thumbnail" src="<%= design["thumbnailURL"] %>">` to `<img class="thumbnail" src="/<%= design["thumbnailURL"] %>">` or you can make sure to inclue the "/" in the value for the `design["thumbnailURL"]` I hope that this is of help

Comment: sorry for the confusion. test.com is not our actual site. the actual site wasn't linked for fear of people claiming spam. will share the actual site in another comment then delete it after you view it.

Comment: https://hotpot.ai/templates/app_store_panorama this is the page where the broken thumbnails (sometimes) appear. will delete once you read this comment. thanks for the help!

Comment: just shared the site in the previous comment

Comment: sorry to say but nothing looks broken :(

Comment: was it the same problem? did that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use assets pipeline?
if yes, do precompile first by

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

then try

```rb
# attempt 1
<img class="thumbnail" src="<%= 'assets/' + design["thumbnailURL"] %>">
# because the images would be compiled and under public/assets/
# I don't know exactly what's design["thumbnailURL"] contain, so I list this attempt

# attempt 2
<%= image_tag design["thumbnailURL"], alt: '...', class: 'thumbnail' %>
# image_tag will also append SHA256 suffix in the filename
# in production environment, all the assets will be appended a SHA256 to let the browser know its the latest assets, ex: aaa.jpg will be aaa-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.jpg, it may be the cause the browser cannot find the right one and return 404

# attempt 3
# if you don't want the images being precomiled, just put original images under public/ rather than app/assets/images/
# design["thumbnailURL"] should be the relative path to public/
# and you can remain your <img ...> same in view
# however, if you update the image, the users who already have been to your site would cache the old image and your new image will not be shown on their browser
```

deploy the new code and see if it works

Comment: hi thanks for this but we don’t use the assets pipeline.

Comment: where are your images saved? in public?

Comment: @MZaragoza yes saved in the public folder so we just use direct links to each image file